# Unable to locate iframe in Selenium Webdriver(java)

Tags: java, testing, iframe, automation, selenium-webdriver

I want to select a element of iframe which is located with in a popup window. I am able go inside popup window but not able to locate iframe. Below is html code of popup window.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" border="0" src="/some/url.do?parameter=getData">
<html>
 .
 .
 <table id="ec_table" class="tableRegion" width="20%" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2" 
 border="0">
 <tr class="even">
 <td>
 <input type="radio" value="173" name="hier_data_id">
 </td>
 </tr>
 .
 .
 </html>
 </iframe>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Here I want to click Radio button which is located inside iframe. I used below code to switch with in iframe but it is not switching to iframe.

```
 driver.switchTo().frame(myD.findElement(By.tag("iframe")));
```

As iframe doesn't have id, i'm finding difficulty locate elements inside iframe.

Does anyone know how I could do it..?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can switch to a frame by its index . Try the following:

```
//go to popup
//switch to the first frame , assuming there's only one frame with no id or name
driver.switchTo().frame(0);
driver.findElement(By.name("hier_data_id")).click();
```

Answer (score 2):

As iframe has id refer [HERE](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) and your answer is as follows

```
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" border="0" id="iframe"
                  src="/some/url.do?parameter=getData">
```

and your code is

```
driver.switchTo().frame(myD.findElement(By.id("iframe")));
```

Comment: I tried with above code(iframe id), still not able to  identify iframe elements. Strange thing is, test case is not failing even timeout limit exceeds. Please let me know if you need even more details.

Answer (score 0):

//iframe[@src="/some/url.do?parameter=getData"]

But this might be a timing & loading issue. So you might be trying to write/read/interact with the iframe before the content has loaded. Try checking for the element before selecting it. And wait if it's not present.

Answer (score 0):

here are the code for selecting the iFrame and enter text "Test data"

```
$x = $I->grabAttributeFrom('//iframe', 'id');
$I->switchToIframe($x);
$I->fillField('#tinymce', 'Test data');
$I->switchToWindow();`
```

If you have two iFrame one after another You can switch through this function

```
$I->switchToWindow();
```